# Is the way I free my nodes correct?

Tags: c, list, pointers

So I have a structure like this:

```
main1 -> main2 -> main3 -> .... ->main 13
  |        |        |               |
  v        v        v               v
node1    node1    node1            node1
  |        |        |               |
  v        v        v               v
node2    node2    node2            node2
```

So I can have up to 5 nodes under each main, of course the last node5 under each main has NULL for next down pointer.

Here is my code

```
    //free stacks of cards                                                                                                                                                                                             
card_pos_ptr freeList(card_pos_ptr list){
  int i, j;
  int count = 1;
  card_pos_ptr current = list;
  card_ptr current_card = current->card_stack;
  //traverse entire clock to free every single card                                                                                                                                                                
    for(i=0;i<13;i++){
      //reset the position of current card according to clock position                                                                                                                                             
      current_card = current->card_stack;
      //get the numbers of cards in the stack to be freed                                                                                                                                                          
      while(current_card->down != NULL){
        count++;
        current_card = current_card->down;
      }
      //free cards @ each stack depend on how many cards in there                                                                                                                                                  
      card_pos_ptr current_pos = current;
      if(count == 5){
    free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down->down->down);
    free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down->down);
    free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down);
    free(current_pos->card_stack->down);
    free(current_pos->card_stack);
      }
      if(count == 4){
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack);
      }else if(count == 3){
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack);

      }else if(count == 2){
        free(current_pos->card_stack->down);
        free(current_pos->card_stack);
      }else{
        free(current_pos->card_stack);
      }

      current = current->next_pos;
    }
    //change the pointer position back to A from K                                                                                                                                                                 
    current = list;
    return current;
}
```

So what I do is that I go to each main and go down and free each node, is that done correctly the way I do it?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just `return list ;` at the end of your function?

Comment: You may also want to set each `current_pos->card_stack = NULL`

Comment: it would yield the smame result as current = list then return current right? I mean since... current start from list anyway?

Comment: I going to use recursion... it look much more elegant than the switch or my stupid big code... thank GUYS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to free() card_stack from bottom to top, recursion might be the way to go:

```
void freecardstack(card_ptr * acard)
{
  if ( acard-> next ) freecardstack( acard-> next ) ;
  free( acard) ;
}
```

And then in your loop:

```
freecardstack( current->card_stack ) ;
current-> card_stack= NULL ;
```

However, the heap (where you get memory) doesn't really care what order you deallocate in.  You can free the cards from front to back as long as you don't reference the contents after the free(), so you have to store the next pointer in a temporary before you do the free:

```
{
  card_ptr * tempcard ;

  for ( current_card= current-> card_stack ; ( current_card ) ; current_card= tempcard )
  {
     tempcard= current_card-> next ;
     free( current_card ) ;
  }
  current-> card_stack= NULL ;
}
```

Comment: wow, much shorter than what I have, thank you. I should think about recursion more.

Comment: `current_pos->card_stack = NULL` or you are begging for a use-after-free bug.

Comment: I will change it to NULL, thank you, cause I will keep all the main node alive for another round of usage.

Answer (score 1):

if the last `down` points to NULL, you can do something like this:

```
void post_order(card c)
{
  if (c) {
    post_order(c->down);
    free(c)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, DON'T EVER do such allocation and free in your code unless you absolutely have to. My experience, this never happened to me so I never do such allocation in any of my code in any circumstances.

The answer to your question is as following:
Redesign your data structure and logic.

If the code gets this tedious, chances are you haven't thought thoroughly regarding what the data is for and how they interact with each other.

For instance, for the above case, you can create one class/structure for node and one class/structure for main:
1. Main will have pointer to one node and the next main. To free all mains, first main call free for connected node and main. It then block wait for the call to return before freeing itself. If the main has no nodes or main, that routine will return instantly.
2. Node will have pointer to connect node only, effectively a singly linked list. When freeing a node, call free to it's connected node recursively until hit a NULL and return. This will free the whole node list and return to upper level main.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have an awful lot of code to basically "free cards until we reach a NULL". There's no reason you have to free them bottom-to-top.

```
while(current_card != NULL){
    card_ptr collector = current_card;
    current_card = current_card->down;
    free(collector);
}
```

Also, you **need** to set `current->card_stack = NULL`, otherwise it will be pointing at `free`'d memory.

`j` is unused. Eliminate it.

Instead of assigning `list` to `current` and then returning `current`, cut out the middle-man and just return `list` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to keep using your `count` variable, here's a way you can reduce the amount of code in your if-else chain:

```
  switch(count){
    default: // uh oh, more than 5 cards?
    case 5:
      free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down->down->down);
    case 4:
      free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down->down);
    case 3:
      free(current_pos->card_stack->down->down);
    case 2:
      free(current_pos->card_stack->down);
    case 1:
      free(current_pos->card_stack);
    case 0:
      current_pos->card_stack = NULL;  // Prevent use after free!
  }
```

Comment: Come on, if you're going to be clever, go all the way and use the fall through switch statement.

Comment: @woolstar sir, yes sir! ;)